# Excel - MATCH function - multiple search results

Tags: excel, function, search, match, keyword

I am trying to create an excel tool which would search for specific key words located in a separate sheet and display results (full sentences/paragraphs including those key words). As of now I could only manage to display only the first finding. What I would like to do is to display all findings below each other.

The functions I am using are:
    `=IFERROR((INDEX(Tabulka!A:A;POZVYHLEDAT(CONCATENATE("*";FINDER!C4;"*";FINDER!C5;"*";FINDER!C6;"*";FINDER!C7;"*";FINDER!C8;"*");Tabulka!A:A;0)));"N/A")`

where Tabulka is a sheet where the table with sentences/paragraphs is located and FINDER is a sheet where I define the key words and desplay search results.

There can be more sentences in Tabulka sheet including the same defined key words in FINDER sheet. I want the function to display them all below each other not only the first one as it does now.

Is it possible to solve this issue somehow with and/or without VBA?

Thanks

J.

Comment: Do you want the search word to appear anywhere in the sentence even inside other words eg 'play' matches 'display' or exact matched words only which means 'sentence' won't match 'sentences'.

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes, it should appear anywhere in the sentence as shown in your example. Also, the order of the defined key words should not necessarily reflect the order of the words in the sentences. I mean, if you for example define those key words: dog, cat, the following sentence should also be displayed as result: Cats are usually smaller than dogs. This is actually what concatenate function cannot do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that uses a [Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/). The search pattern is build from the words in column C. The results are shown in columns A and B. Column A has the cell reference.

```vb
    Sub SEARCH()

        Const COL_WORDS As String = "C"
        Const COL_RESULTS As String = "B"
        Const SHT_RESULTS As String = "FINDER"
        Const SHT_SEARCH As String = "Tabulka"

        Dim wb As Workbook, wsToSearch As Worksheet, wsResults As Worksheet
        Dim t0 As Single
        t0 = Timer

        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set wsToSearch = wb.Sheets(SHT_SEARCH)
        Set wsResults = wb.Sheets(SHT_RESULTS)

        ' build array of key words without blanks
        Dim i As Integer, irow As Long, iLastRow As Long
        Dim words() As String, cell As Range

        ' last row of keywords
        iLastRow = wsResults.Range(COL_WORDS & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

        ReDim words(iLastRow)
        i = 0
        For Each cell In wsResults.Range(COL_WORDS & "1:" & COL_WORDS & iLastRow)
          If Len(cell) > 0 Then
            words(i) = cell.Value
            i = i + 1
          End If
        Next
        ReDim Preserve words(i - 1)

        ' build regex engine
        Dim regex As Object, sPattern As String
        sPattern = Join(words, "|")
        Debug.Print sPattern

        Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        With regex
          .Global = True
          .MultiLine = True
          .Pattern = sPattern
          .IgnoreCase = True
        End With

        ' scan sheet and record results under keywords
        Dim count As Integer, matches As Integer
        count = 0: matches = 0
        irow = iLastRow + 2
        For Each cell In wsToSearch.UsedRange
           If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
             count = count + 1
             If regex.test(cell.Value) Then
               wsResults.Cells(irow, 1) = cell.Address
               cell.Copy wsResults.Range(COL_RESULTS & irow)
               irow = irow + 1
               matches = matches + 1
             End If
           End If
        Next

        ' format results sheet
        wsResults.Columns(COL_RESULTS).ColumnWidth = 100

         ' performance stats
        Dim sMsg As String
        sMsg = count & " cells scanned and " & matches & " matches found " _
        & " in " & Int(Timer - t0) & " seconds."
        MsgBox sMsg, vbInformation, "Result"

    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I just found out that if the keywords are all text or numbers it works fine, but if one keyword is a text and the other number, it shows zero matches even if there must be a match. I tried to solve it by a condition with IsNumber so I could convert integer to string but this did not help at all. Do you please have any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: @Jakub What format is the column with the words in. Try making them text using words(i) = trim(cstr(cell.Value)) inside the first loop. Look for hidden spaces in the Immediate window for Debug.Print sPattern.